# "the consumer blind spot"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Human beings are social animals, linked together by shared beliefs and values. This is both a weakness and a strength. Brands use this fact against us by tapping into the pulsing collective mass of our shared fears, hopes, desires and anxieties and **the consumer blind spots** which offer the greatest opportunity for exploitation are related to the murky area of emotions and feelings.*

Source: https://www.irishexaminer.com/lifestyle/features/how-to-survive-christmas-463410.html

I am not sure how to understand the passage in bold, especially "the consumer blind spot". Can it be rewritten as "the consumer ignorance" or "the consumer Achilles heel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blind spot refers to driving. When you look in the rear-view mirror of some cars, you cannot always see the vehicle behind you. The vehicle is said to be "in your blind spot". This is an very common image in English. So, it is actually somewhat dangerous.

You can replace any image you like. But that is editing.

Comment: I'd say the *primary* meaning of "blind spot" is [*the point of entry of the optic nerve on the retina, insensitive to light.*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2jlfDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT429&lpg=PT429&dq=define+blind+spot+%22the+point+of+entry+of+the+optic+nerve+on+the+retina,+insensitive+to+light.%22&source=bl&ots=abhlSYSXIA&sig=VPuVkITl66CWgvCHzsHUNIkhv7s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif1-vsl7veAhWD66QKHUuyBuoQ6AEwE3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=define%20blind%20spot%20%22the%20point%20of%20entry%20of%20the%20optic%20nerve%20on%20the%20retina%2C%20insensitive%20to%20light.%22&f=false)

Comment: That's very ophthalmalogical. Would most people know that? Dunno. I don't think that "in one's blind spot" refers to that actually. Merriam Webster 2:  an area in which one fails to exercise judgment or discrimination

Comment: But you must have noticed that the ***first*** definition given by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blind%20spot) is ***the small circular area at the back of the retina where the optic nerve enters the eyeball and which is devoid of rods and cones and is not sensitive to light***. And I expect that would be the same for most dictionaries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, but that is not the metaphorical use of it, is it? You can't say: I didn't see that, it was in (my eye's) blind spot. Of course, there is also the circle of confusion. I see no reason to always give every single thing if it is not relevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It would be a mistake to think that the first sense listed under a dictionary's definition of a word is always its primary meaning (or that there even is a primary meaning).

Comment: to have a blind spot means that something is obstructed in one's **field of vision**. The small circular area at the back of the retina is not one's field of vision.